# Swift - retain cycle not with self?

Tags: ios, swift, retain-cycle

The question is really simple.
I know to detect retain cycles but i wanna know if in the next example i have retain cycle.

```
    MainManager.sound.player.speak("1", didFinish: {

        MainManager.sound.player.speak("3", didFinish: {

            MainManager.sound.player.speak("4", didFinish: {

            })
        })
    })
```

`MainManager` is a singleton class that keep `sound` in a strong ref, and `sound` keep `player` class in strong ref.

The implementation of speak()

```
private var speechSynthesizer:AVSpeechSynthesizer?
private var speechDidFinishCompletion:CompletionVoid? = nil
func speak(_ stringToSpeak:String, didFinish:CompletionVoid? = nil)
{
    if speechSynthesizer == nil
    {
        speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        speechSynthesizer?.delegate = self
    }

    speechDidFinishCompletion = didFinish

    let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: stringToSpeak)
    speechSynthesizer!.speak(speechUtterance)
}

func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)
{
    speechDidFinishCompletion?()
}
```

Comment: Could you post the implementation of `speak` method?

Comment: Retain cycle with what exactly? By the looks of things, you're just referring to static members. It would be most helpful if you could provide some more context.

Comment: i'v just edit the question can you take a look pls?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends".

If `MainManager` has a strong reference to `sound` and `sound` has a strong reference to `player` and `player.speak()` makes `player` keep a strong reference to the closure that it can't get rid of, then yes, you have a strong reference cycle.

If, however, `speak` just puts the closure in an asynchronous queue and never references it again, you will be OK.

Comment: Thanks, i'v just edit the question can you take a look pls?

Answer (score 0):

You have a potential retain cycle because you're not letting go of the reference after you call the completion handler. As long as the closure is no longer referenced by the instance of `sound`, the cycle can be broken. Your current "recursive" call ensures the first 2 callbacks are released because they're overwritten by the subsequent calls. Since the final one isn't overwritten and if the final closure has a retain cycle, this code creates a cycle.

You should be able to safely get rid of the reference to the completion handler as follows.

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
    // Transfer ownership to the local scope in case the
    // closure itself sets `speechDidFinishCompletion`
    let localClosure = speechDidFinishCompletion
    speechDidFinishCompletion = nil

    localClosure?()
}
```